# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'

Tags: firebase, file, flutter, error-handling, imagepicker

So far in my app everything is working except that one error I keep getting:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'
```

I tried many ways to try and fix the Issue but nothing has yet been resolved.

I can understand where the issue is, but I'm unable to fix it with countless attempts.

The problem is that im passing an `Image` using `ImagePicker gallery` im passing that image data to firebase as `image: image.toString()` and it works fine. Firebase takes the path but as an error i get: `_file != null` since the image is indeed a `File image` I cant fetch the data from firebase and pass the string path as an argument. therefore getting this error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'`. I display the image on the app like the following `Image.file(image)` Since its the only way to display a File image and use the `ImagePicker`. Is there a solution for this? or is it a bad way of doing the idea im trying to achieve?

here is the code:

image picker:

```
String img;

  static Future<String> fileToB64(File f) async {
    List<int> imageBytes = f.readAsBytesSync();

    return base64Encode(
      imageBytes,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      data.image = imageFile;
    });
    fileToB64(imageFile).then((d) {
      setState(() {
        img = d; //base64Decode(d);
      });
    });
  }
```

the provider:

```
import: 'dart:io';

class AddCar {
  // other data
  File image;

  AddCar({
    this.// other data
    this.image,
  });
}
```

firebase data:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetCars() async {
    const url = 'https://mylink.firebaseio.com/cars.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<AddCar> loadedCars = [];
      extractedData.forEach((carId, carData) {
        loadedCars.add(AddCar(
          // other data
          image: carData['image'],
        ));
      });
      _cars = loadedCars;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  AddCar findById(String id) {
    return _cars.firstWhere((carProd) => carProd.id == id);
  }

  void addCar(AddCar car) {
    const url = 'https://mylink.firebaseio.com/cars.json';
    http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        // other data
        'image': car.image.toString(),
      }),
    );
    final newCar = AddCar(
    // other data
      image: car.image,
    );
    _cars.insert(0, newCar); // add car at the top of the list
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

how im displaying the fetch data from firebase:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
  Provider.of<Cars>(context).fetchAndSetCars();
 });
    super.initState();
  }
```

how im calling the data to be displayed in the app:

```
Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Image.file(
                    image,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                      MyCarDetails.routeName,
                      arguments: id,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

What I get when I run the app:

```
Restarted application in 6,085ms.
E/flutter ( 3497): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'
E/flutter ( 3497): #0      Cars.fetchAndSetCars 
package:flutter_app/providers/car_provider.dart:54
E/flutter ( 3497): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3497): #1      _CarAreaState.initState.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter_app/home_parts/cars_area.dart:28
E/flutter ( 3497): #2      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 3497): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 3497): #4      _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter ( 3497): #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter ( 3497): #6      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter ( 3497): #7      Future._complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:512:7)
E/flutter ( 3497): #9      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
E/flutter ( 3497): #10     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 3497): #11     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
E/flutter ( 3497): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
E/flutter ( 3497): #13     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter ( 3497): #14     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 3497): #15     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
E/flutter ( 3497): #16     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
E/flutter ( 3497): #17     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
E/flutter ( 3497): #18     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
E/flutter ( 3497): #19     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: @Lekr0 just added some code check it out

Comment: please provide stacktrace too

Comment: @Marc just added something at the bottom is that what you meant??

Comment: yeah, thats a stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that instead of doing this:

```
image: carData['image']
```

You should do this:

```
image: File(carData['image'])
```

Because `carData['image']` is a `String`, not a `File`, and `AddCar` expects a `File`.

Comment: I tried that and got the following error: `The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CarItem(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#5f0e8], _InheritedTheme, MediaQuery]):
The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +("50")`

Comment: followed by this `User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    ListView 
lib\home_parts\cars_area.dart:67
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      CarItem.build 
package:flutter_app/widget/car_item.dart:151
#2      StatelessElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4009
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3941
#4      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
...`

Comment: the value `50` was called from my price `TextFormField` I also tried `carData[File('image')],` but didnt work either

Comment: I can't help you with that because I don't see the code of CarItem...

Comment: Im showing it in the "how im calling the data to be displayed in the app:" part unless you want more code let me know so i can provide more

Comment: It seems that the problem of your question was solved and now you're facing another problem. You could try a little more to solve it and then if you are stuck ask another question. By the way, the CarItem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Ah i see. I did post a snippet of how im displaying the image in the CarItem. you are correct I didnt include the entire CarItem becasue its an entire page of code and I just wanted to highlight the image displaying way im using

Comment: Also got this error i didnt see. `E/flutter ( 3497): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: A Cars was used after being disposed.
E/flutter ( 3497): Once you have called dispose() on a Cars, it can no longer be used.`

Comment: Please, spent some time trying to solve these issues and then if you can't ask another question.